# Missed Canada passport submission request timeline

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, canada, canadian-permanent-residents

I received my passport submission request from IRCC in October 2021. I somehow missed this email and just now found out about it. What will happen now? Will my application be cancelled? Will I have to reapply?

I had applied for express entry pnp to Ontario from India and received the mail to submit passport for visa stamping to confirm my COPR.

I did not see this email because just a few days after this email I had received another email from ircc saying they are still processing my application and in the cic portal it still (even now) shows as processing my request.

Comment: What are you applying for?

Comment: I had applied for express entry pnp to Ontario from India and received the mail to submit passport for visa stamping to confirm my COPR. I have updated the post as well.

Answer (score 2):

I remember that the same passport request email also has a passage saying you can contact IRCC directly via both webform/call to explain your situation if you cannot submit passport on time (especially during pandemic)   . If it's allowed , you can still submit your passport after the request timeline.